# vscode "This setting can only be applied in user settings in local window or in remote settings in remote window." error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I want to do unity c# scripting with vscode but,

**error** :

"[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
This project targets .NET version that requires reference assemblies that do not ship with OmniSharp out of the box (e.g. .NET Framework). The most common solution is to make sure Mono is installed on your machine (https://mono-project.com/download/) and that OmniSharp is started with that Mono installation (e.g. "omnisharp.useGlobalMono":"always" in C# Extension for VS Code)."

occurred and I saw someone say to

add "omnisharp.useGlobalMono":"always""

but I can't even add that option.
It says :

This setting can only be applied in user settings in local window or in remote settings in the remote window.

**environment**

os : ubuntu 20.04

mono version :  6.12.0.122

.NET  core version : 5.0.6

unity version : 2020.3.4f1

vs code version : 1.56.2

[image: screen shot]

add:

no unity intellisence are working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps check out the following issue at GitHub, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/539).

It is for another vscode plugin (Maven) but explains fairly well how to change the setting for a local window.

Sometimes editing `.vscode/settings.json` does not work. Some settings need to be in User settings.

In Mac OS you `cmd` + `shift` + `p` then go to `Preferences: User Settings`. From there you could probably edit the desired setting.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Please include the essential parts you find in the links, link-only answers can become invalid once  the linked page changes or shutdown.